# selecting id from svg in d3.js

Tags: svg, d3.js

I'm new to D3.js so I'm wondering how I could use `d3.select()` or `d3.selectAll()` to select some `id`s from an external SVG which I have loaded. For example: I want to select some countries and change their colour and border but can't make it work in D3.js. The relevant script:

```
        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", 2048)
            .attr("height", 982)
            .style("fill", "transparent");
        var g = svg.append("g");

        var img = g.append("svg:image")
            .attr("xlink:href", "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b3/Blank_map_of_Europe.svg")
            .attr("width", 2048)
            .attr("height", 982)
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("y", 0);


        var hr = d3.selectAll("#g").select("#hr").style("fill","green");
```

Comment: It looks like you're selecting elements and then an ID. Try `d3.selectAll("g").select("#hr").style("fill","green");`

Comment: Thanks, I get it work in javascript on distant server, now i just need to do the same in d3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're loading data into an `<image>` tag then you can't manipulate the contents of that image.

You'd need to load the data into your document inline if you want your code to work and do do that the file would need to be in the same domain as the loader file. I.e. loading the file from http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b3/Blank_map_of_Europe.svg is only going to work if the code that loads it is also on http://upload.wikimedia.org/

Assuming you copy the map to the same place as the loading page then you could use [XMLParser](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp) to parse it and then [importNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.importNode) and appendChild to append it to your existing document. Once the map and the code that loads it are all part of the same document the selection code will just work.

Comment: I tought that was a problem.. So i uploaded .html and .svg on server and loaded that svg as object.. Thanks!